# simple google analytics way to count node.js site visits

Tags: node.js, google-analytics

I have a node.js website and I seek a simple way to know if anyone is visiting it.  I have google analytics 4 on my google account panel (I created that account with google), and I want my node.js website to report site visits to it (like people are doing with Wordpress).

In short, I want to go up to my google analytics panel on google and view the site visits (of a node.js website).  I am not trying to go the other way of using node.js to pull data from what I think is a google analytics API.  I am not trying to clone the google analytics dashboard on a site.

This is my website.
https://rocky-temple-91974.herokuapp.com

In google analytics stream I have the Measurement ID copied and ready.  Do I have to add code to my node.js website and paste in the Measurement ID?  Is there a node package I need to install in my site code?

Remember I have google analytics 4 not Universal.

Finally, I see everyone knows how to do this with Wordpress and Shopify.  Wordpress has a plug-in that allows you to paste in the Measurement ID.  I am thus wondering why no one says or knows anything about using google analytics 4 with node.js.  With node.js it seems no one is trying to view the site visits by logging into google analytics and using the google tool.

If google analytics account viewing does not work with node.js I would like to have a code snippet for node.js that would say save counts to a file in my node.js public folder.  I am using mongoDB Atlas and another way would be to save visitor counts to mongoDB.  Any hack like that would be appreciated.

I have not had any luck finding how to use google analytics for node.js (everyone knows how to use Wordpress to do it).

Thanks everyone!  I feel this is a worthy question to ask.

Comment: You may have better luck on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ this doesnt seam to be programming related to me.

Comment: This definately a programming related topic.  Does anyone know how to use node.js with google analytics the way they use Wordpress?

Comment: Google analytics is just a Js snippet just add it https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits this isnt programming related its configuration.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] if you believe this is programming related then please add [example] and describe any issues you are having with your code. Include any error messages or stack trace that may be needed to help you debug your issue.

Comment: Perfect!  The link above answers my exact question.  Thanks.  You may close this ticket.